# change parameters of a function inside that function

Tags: r

I am trying to change all `NA` passed to the function to `NULL`. What I want is not to treat each arg separatedly, by name, but to capture all of them, filter those which are `NA`and change them to NULL.

```
foo <- function(a, b = NA, c = NA) {
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)

    # do something to capture all args and change NAs to NULL

    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
}

# expected output
> foo(a = 1)
[1] 1
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] 1
[1] NULL
[1] NULL
```

edit: included an argument without a default value

Comment: What should happen if it is called with `b = c(1, NA)`?

Comment: It's not the case here, but the functions I call inside the function would make this case give an error.

Comment: So it would be incorrect to convert that to `NULL`?  And what if the argument is already `NULL` because the user called it that way?

Comment: This is a test function actually. No one will call it except me. The reason I want to go through all args is because there will be many different args this function will call. I would like it to be elegant instead of checking through all of them by name. To answer your question, the arg can only be a i32 (will be `NA_integer_` in this case) or it will give an error. The functions inside foo are called first in Rust and after in Python, that's why I am trying to convert to NULL after the call to Rust.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access a function's arguments, use [`formals`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/formals.html).

```r
foo <- function(a = 1, b = NA, c = NA) {
  print(a)
  print(b)
  print(c)
  
  # do something to capture all args and change NAs to NULL
  frm <- formals()
  cat("-----------\n")
  print(frm)
  frm <- lapply(frm, \(x) {
    if(is.na(x)) NULL else x
  })
  cat("-----------\n")
  with(frm, {
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
  })
}
foo()
#> [1] 1
#> [1] NA
#> [1] NA
#> -----------
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> -----------
#> [1] 1
#> NULL
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edit

The comments suggest that the question is also asking for [`match.call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.call.html). But its return values must be coerced to list.

```r
check_arrays <- function(a, b, c, d) { 
  print(as.list(match.call()))
}
check_arrays(a = 'teststring', b = 1, c = NA, d = NA)
#> [[1]]
#> check_arrays
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] "teststring"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And an example changing all `NA` arguments to `NULL`, just like the first function above is the following.

```r
check_arrays <- function(a, b, c, d) {
  print(a)
  print(b)
  print(c)
  print(d)
  
  # do something to capture all args and change NAs to NULL
  # note that the first element of the list is the function 
  # name, remove it
  args_list <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  cat("-----------\n")
  print(args_list)
  args_list <- lapply(args_list, \(x) {
    if(is.na(x)) NULL else x
  })
  cat("-----------\n")
  with(args_list, {
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
    print(d)
  })
}
check_arrays(a = 'teststring', b = 1, c = NA, d = NA)
#> [1] "teststring"
#> [1] 1
#> [1] NA
#> [1] NA
#> -----------
#> $a
#> [1] "teststring"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> -----------
#> [1] "teststring"
#> [1] 1
#> NULL
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That test should probably be `if (any(is.na(x)))` or `if (all(is.na(x)))`.

Comment: @user2554330 You're right but the question is not clear on that, I believe that a comment with a link the the documentation of `formals` might have been enough to answer the question.

Comment: That would work pretty well, but... Do you have any idea why is the output here all blank?  

check_arrays <- function(a, b, c, d) {
    frm <- formals()
    print(frm)
}



> check_arrays(a = 'teststring', b = 1, c = NA, d = NA)
$a


$b


$c


$d

Comment: I got it... It seems formals only captures the default args...

Comment: I will make a small edit, since in my case not all args have a default value. Could you do it with formals even like that?

Comment: @daniellga With `formals` no but with `match.call` yes, see the edit.

Answer (score 4):

Quick disclaimer: the solutions offered here will work if your arguments are scalars.  If they are vectors or other objects, the outcome may be quite a bit different.

You can use a `ls` and `assign` within a loop and avoid having to refer to the arguments from a list after the conversion.

```
foo <- function(a = 1, b = NA, c = NA) {
  print(a)
  print(b)
  print(c)
  
  arg_names <- ls()
  
  for (arg in arg_names){
    tmp <- if (is.na(get(arg))) NULL else get(arg)
    assign(arg, tmp)
  }
  
  print(a)
  print(b)
  print(c)
}

foo()
```

Alternatively, if you'd rather work with lists, you can use `mget` and `list2env`

```
foo <- function(a = 1, b = NA, c = NA) {
  print(a)
  print(b)
  print(c)
  
  arg_names <- ls()
  arg <- mget(arg_names)
  arg <- lapply(arg, 
                function(a) if (is.na(a)) NULL else a)

  list2env(arg, envir = environment())

  print(a)
  print(b)
  print(c)
}

foo()
```

Comment: As I commented on the other answer, that test `if (is.na(get(arg)))` might not work.  It might even cause an error, since `is.na()` doesn't return a logical on every object, e.g. `is.na(NULL)` fails.  A safe test might be `tmp <- get(arg); if (length(tmp) == 1 && is.atomic(tmp) && is.na(tmp)) ...`

Comment: Agreed.  I will add a disclaimer that this will produce undesirable results unless the arguments are scalars.

Comment: While this case works, I think it will modify all variables in the function scope, instead of only the functions's arguments. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @daniellga:  That's correct, but if this code comes early in the function there are no other variables in scope.  R doesn't do "hoisting" like Javascript does.

Comment: Yes, it will modify in scope. That may have advantages or disadvantages, depending on the use case. As @user2554330 indicates, you would likely want to use this very early in the function. If that isn't an option, Rui's answer is going to have more advantages.

Comment: Actually the use of `formals`, like the answer above showed, doesn't seem to work when there are no default values to an argument.

Comment: Beginning in R 4.2, `if(x) ...` will [give an error if `x` is not scalar](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html). So the next R version will break this solution if there are any non-scalar inputs